# How might I clean up this lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression

I have an expression that I use a few times in several LINQ queries so I separated it out into it's own method that returns the expression. The lambda portion of the function is kind of messy looking. Anyone want to take a crack at refactoring it and making it more readable and/or smaller?

```
    private Expression<Func<Message, bool>> UserSelector(string username, bool sent)
    {
        return x => ((sent ? x.FromUser : x.ToUser).Username.ToLower() == username.ToLower()) && (sent ? !x.SenderDeleted : !x.RecipientDeleted);
    }
```

A quick English description of what it's doing is it is checking the boolean `sent` and checking either the `Message.FromUser` or the `Message.ToUser` based on that boolean.

If the user is looking at his/her outbox, `sent` is true and it will see if `x.FromUser.Username == username` and `x.SenderDeleted == false`.

If the user is looking at his/her inbox then it does the same logic, but sent is false and it checks `x.ToUser` and `x.RecipientDeleted` instead.

Maybe this is the easiest way but I'm open to some refactoring.

### ANSWER EDIT

I really liked Davy8's answer but I decided to take a step further and do two expressions instead of one expression with a nested function. Now I have the following methods:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Expression to determine if a message belongs to a user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">The name of the user.</param>
    /// <param name="sent">True if retrieving sent messages.</param>
    /// <returns>An expression to be used in a LINQ query.</returns>
    private Expression<Func<Message, bool>> MessageBelongsToUser(string username, bool sent)
    {
        return x => (sent ? x.FromUser : x.ToUser).Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Expression to determine if a message has been deleted by the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">The name of the user.</param>
    /// <param name="sent">True if retrieving sent messages.</param>
    /// <returns>An expression to be used in a LINQ query.</returns>
    private Expression<Func<Message, bool>> UserDidNotDeleteMessage(string username, bool sent)
    {
        return x => sent ? !x.SenderDeleted : !x.RecipientDeleted;
    }
```

So now my queries look like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a list of messages from the data context for a user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">The name of the user.</param>
    /// <param name="page">The page number.</param>
    /// <param name="itemsPerPage">The number of items to display per page.</param>
    /// <param name="sent">True if retrieving sent messages.</param>
    /// <returns>An enumerable list of messages.</returns>
    public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessagesBy_Username(string username, int page, int itemsPerPage, bool sent)
    {
        var query = _dataContext.Messages
            .Where(MessageBelongsToUser(username, sent))
            .Where(UserDidNotDeleteMessage(username, sent))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.SentDate)
            .Skip(itemsPerPage * (page - 1))
            .Take(itemsPerPage);
        return query;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the total number of messages for the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">The name of the user.</param>
    /// <param name="sent">True if retrieving the number of messages sent.</param>
    /// <returns>The total number of messages.</returns>
    public int GetMessageCountBy_Username(string username, bool sent)
    {
        var query = _dataContext.Messages
            .Where(MessageBelongsToUser(username, sent))
            .Where(UserDidNotDeleteMessage(username, sent))
            .Count();
        return query;
    }
```

I would say those are some very English readable queries, thanks guys!

Reference: http://www.codetunnel.com/blog/post/64/how-to-simplify-complex-linq-expressions

Comment: I'd recommend moving this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it out into a separate function:

```
    private Expression<Func<Message, bool>> UserSelector(string username, bool sent)
    {
        return message=> InnerFunc(message, username, sent);
    }

    private static bool InnerFunc(Message message, string username, bool sent)
    {
        if(sent)
        {
            return string.Equals(message.FromUser.Username, username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !message.SenderDeleted;
        }
        return string.Equals(message.ToUser.Username, username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !message.RecipientDeleted;
    }
```

Or alternatively it can be inlined to maintain closure usage:

```
    private Expression<Func<Message, bool>> UserSelector(string username, bool sent)
    {
        Func<Message, bool> innerFunc = message =>
        {
            if (sent)
            {
                return string.Equals(message.FromUser.Username, username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                        !message.SenderDeleted;
            }
            return string.Equals(message.ToUser.Username, username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                    !message.RecipientDeleted;
        };
        return message => innerFunc(message);
    }
```

(Edited to use `string.Equals` with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` for odd edge cases with different culture settings.)

Comment: I like the idea of two functions and doing two `.Where` chains on the collection, one for each expression. This is very readable.

Comment: Take a look at my edit for my implementation of your answer :)

Comment: @Davy8 I deleted my answer but I think the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same) to Jeffrey L Whitledge's answer to [are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same) might put the InvariantCultureIgnoreCase bit in context

Comment: Believe it or not I actually had to remove the string.Equals from my expression. It didn't like it. I had to go back to `.ToLower()`. The app would compile, but then at runtime it would say "invalid number of arguments supplied for method string.Equals". I triple checked the arguments, even debugged it and they were getting passed. Just didn't like it in an expression. If I did it up in the main method it worked fine, just not in the expression.

Comment: Okay, I got string.Equals to work, but only by calling its instance equivalent. Instead of `string.Equals(str, str, ignoreCase)` I call `str.Equals(str, ignoreCase)` and that seems to work okay in an expression. Seems that calling the static string class was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Resharper? A lot of times I'll write something like this as a foreach loop and see if Resharper can refactor it.   I think readability, though, is most important, although you should evaluate the peformance of any solution you come up with.

Comment: Someone care to clarify why they downvoted this? Just interested in what was wrong with it.

Comment: The reply is too generic to be a particular answer to the original question.

Comment: The answer is implied. Don't write a complicated 1 liner LINQ statement, unless you feel that performance is more important than readability, which is not usually the case.

Comment: @Codism, I see. I agree with that. Could have been a comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you write the description you wrote for this question as a comment, it should help anyone trying to read / understand it correct?

Comment: Right, I'm just seeing what you guys can come up with that's all. I'm often surprised by how much easier people manage to do things than I thought possible.